# How to use Instant/JodaDateTimeConverter with Spring Data Elasticsearch

Tags: spring-data-elasticsearch

There's a class JodaDateTimeConverter which apparently is designed to store Instant fields with Spring Data Elasticsearch. But how do I use it? I haven't found any examples.

Trying to use Instant as a Date field:

```
@Field(index = FieldIndex.analyzed, type = Date)
private Instant someTime;
```

gives me this exception:

```
Caused by: java.lang.IllegalArgumentException: unknown property [epochSecond]
    at org.elasticsearch.index.mapper.core.DateFieldMapper.innerParseCreateField(DateFieldMapper.java:520)
    at org.elasticsearch.index.mapper.core.NumberFieldMapper.parseCreateField(NumberFieldMapper.java:241)
    at org.elasticsearch.index.mapper.FieldMapper.parse(FieldMapper.java:321)
    ... 21 more
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I found a workaround for this issue by using a custom object mapper as described in https://github.com/spring-projects/spring-data-elasticsearch/wiki/Custom-ObjectMapper and configuring Jackson to serialize Instants as timestamps:

```
public class CustomEntityMapper implements EntityMapper {

private ObjectMapper objectMapper;

public CustomEntityMapper(ObjectMapper objectMapper) {
    this.objectMapper = objectMapper;
    objectMapper.configure(SerializationFeature.WRITE_DATE_TIMESTAMPS_AS_NANOSECONDS, false);
    objectMapper.configure(SerializationFeature.WRITE_DATES_AS_TIMESTAMPS, true);
    objectMapper.configure(DeserializationFeature.READ_DATE_TIMESTAMPS_AS_NANOSECONDS, false);
}

@Override
public String mapToString(Object object) throws IOException {
    return objectMapper.writeValueAsString(object);
}

@Override
public <T> T mapToObject(String source, Class<T> clazz) throws IOException {
    return objectMapper.readValue(source, clazz);
}
```

}

Spring configuration code:

```
    @Bean
    @Autowired
    public ElasticsearchTemplate elasticsearchTemplate(Client client) {
        ObjectMapper objectMapper = new ObjectMapper();
        objectMapper.registerModule(new JavaTimeModule());
        return new ElasticsearchTemplate(client, new CustomEntityMapper(objectMapper));
    }
```

Answer (score 0):

Using this method breaks automatic Id resolution if you are using es generated Id's. See my post here - [spring-data-elastic Id field not populated on reads when using CustomEntityMapper](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/42166936/spring-data-elastic-id-field-not-populated-on-reads-when-using-customentitymappe)

Answer (score -1):

Consider, when using repositories...

```
@Document(indexName = "ESINDEX", type = "TYPE", shards = 5)
public class YourClass implements java.io.Serializable {

@Id
private String url;

.
. 
.

@Field(type = FieldType.Date, format = DateFormat.date_optional_time)
private Date created;
@Field(type = FieldType.Date, format = DateFormat.date_optional_time)
private Date updated;

.
.
}
```

Comment: But I'm not using Date, I'm using Instant.